# Confluence Create Button

Tags: selenium-webdriver, confluence

I'm creating a new Page in Confluence with Selenium.
However after clicking create, I'm unable to click the send create button.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("create-page-button")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='create-dialog']/div/div[2]/button")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("content_title")).sendKeys("Test Case 1");
driver.findElement(By.id("rte-button-publish")).click();
```

The code errors on:

```
Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"content_title"}
```

as the new page has not been created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what it took to create a page for myself:

```
    driver.findElement(By.id("create-page-button")).click();

    (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
            return d.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='create-dialog']/div/div[2]/button")).getText().equals("Create");
        }
    });

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='create-dialog']/div/div[2]/button")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content-title']")).sendKeys("My Test Page");
    driver.findElement(By.id("rte-button-publish")).click();
```

I tried using the `By.id` for the `content-title` input box but it didn't work with the error being the same one as you received however doing it by xpath worked.

Also the `NewDriverWait` was added since the dialog box is loaded in and if you click the `Create` button too fast it would actually be the `Next` button which would result in the page not being created.